# What did I miss about WM_MOUSEMOVE?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse

What I am going to do is very simple, I want to hide the mouse cursor after 1 second if the move does not move or click.

I searched and saw someone recommends using WM_MOUSEMOVE. In my app, however, WM_MOUSEMOVE is simply a dectection of whether the mouse is in the client area. If it is, the app receives WM_MOUSEMOVE continually. I've read the MSDN page but I am still confused.

Comment: I agree that Windows messages are confusing. But WM_MOUSEMOVE contains the coordinates of the mouse at the time the message is sent. So every time you capture the event, compare the coordinates to those of the previous message (stored in globals), and if they are the same and it has been at least 1 second, hide the cursor, but if they are different, the mouse has moved so reset whatever you're using to track the time.

Comment: So that's the implication of WM_MOUSEMOVE? Why do I see people saying simply detecting WM_MOUSEMOVE will do?

Answer (score 1):

Use WM_SETCURSOR.

Use WM_SETCURSOR for cursor related works. This message is made for that purpose. Your mentioning of client area suggest you probably need to use `SetCapture` API also.

Another way (or more modern way of doing) is using `TrackMouseEvent`. It provides [WM_MOUSEHOVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: WM_SETCURSOR usually won't be sent if the mouse isn't moving, so it isn't good for a timeout scenario.

Comment: @Mark Ooch, you are right. I just want to write some warning about handling cursor without considering the setcusor message.

Comment: Getting the exactly same undesired result after replacing WM_MOUSEMOVE with WM_SETCURSOR. I remember seeing a post here saying that these two messages usually come in a pair.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is correct. What you need to do is define a timer (for example, one that triggers the WM_TIMER message).
You activate it in the first mouse movement (WM_MOUSEMOVE). If a mouse movement won't occur within the interval you defined for the timer, the WM_TIMER event will fire and you can then hide the mouse.

Each time the WM_MOUSEMOVE event fires, you simply restart the timer (using its dedicated API). So that WM_MOUSEMONVE events prevent the timer from expiring. If WM_MOUSEMOVE stop arriving (because you don't move the mouse anymore), the timer will tick without interrupts until it elapses and fires.

Comment: That is not the problem. What I mean is I always receive WM_MOUSEMOVE regardless of the real move movement if the mouse is in the client area.

Comment: If the mouse is not moving and the window hierarchy is stable, then if you're still receiving a constant stream of `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages, it's likely due to [third-party so-called enhancement software](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/17/9763416.aspx), or maybe a buggy mouse driver.

Comment: @jonhopkins, I see. But one more thing, as I'm new to stackoverflow, I don't know how to set your "comment" as the answer to the question.

Comment: @LeOpArD comments cannot be selected as the answer. I reread the text from MSDN that I posted, and realized the wording was not implying that WM_MOUSEMOVE is meant to constantly be sent as I originally thought. Why it is doing that in your app, I have no idea. But checking the coordinates, in combination with CodeChord's answer seems to be your best bet if you're receiving the message even when the mouse hasn't moved.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield, it seems more complicated than I thought. But my movie player and PowerPoint Slide show works fine in hiding the cursor.

Comment: @LeOpArD, follow the recommendation in this answer but also add a test to see if the mouse coordinates have changed since the last time you received a WM_MOUSEMOVE and if not ignore it. I too have run into the problem of unexplained extra WM_MOUSEMOVE messages but that was many years ago.